# Determine MAX Decimal Scale Used on a Column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, decimal, precision

In MS SQL, I need a approach to determine the largest scale being used by the rows for a certain decimal column.

For example Col1 Decimal(19,8) has a scale of 8, but I need to know if all 8 are actually being used, or if only 5, 6, or 7 are being used.

Sample Data:

```
123.12345000
321.43210000
5255.12340000
5244.12345000
```

For the data above, I'd need the query to either return 5, or 123.12345000 or 5244.12345000.

I'm not concerned about performance, I'm sure a full table scan will be in order, I just need to run the query once.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Not pretty, but I think it should do the trick:

```
-- Find the first non-zero character in the reversed string...
-- And then subtract from the scale of the decimal + 1.
SELECT 9 - PATINDEX('%[1-9]%', REVERSE(Col1))
```

Comment: Not pretty, but Brilliant. Works like a charm.  Just added the MAX(), and filtered out 0.00000000.  Adding MAX() gave me: SELECT MAX(9 - PATINDEX('%[1-9]%', REVERSE(Col1)))

Answer (score 8):

I like [@Michael Fredrickson's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8978081/determine-max-decimal-scale-used-on-a-column/8978179#8978179) better and am only posting this as an alternative for specific cases where the actual scale is unknown but is certain to be no more than 18:

```
SELECT LEN(CAST(CAST(REVERSE(Col1) AS float) AS bigint))
```

Please note that, although there are two explicit CAST calls here, the query actually performs two more implicit conversions:

1. As the argument of REVERSE, `Col1` is converted to a string.
2. The `bigint` is cast as a string before being used as the argument of LEN.

Comment: You helped find a solution to this one: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14715318/114029 I had to go even further and used this guy's post to get there: http://connectsql.blogspot.com.br/2011/04/normal-0-microsoftinternetexplorer4.html It's interesting how one gets to a solution building upon scattered pieces of info here and there... :D

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT
    MAX(CHAR_LENGTH(
        SUBSTRING(column_name::text FROM '\.(\d*?)0*$')
    )) AS max_scale
FROM table_name;
```

`*?` is the non-greedy version of `*`, so `\d*?` catches all digits after the decimal point except trailing zeros.

The pattern contains a pair of parentheses, so the portion of the text that matched the first parenthesized subexpression (that is `\d*?`) is returned.

References:

- https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/sql-createcast.html
- https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/functions-matching.html

Answer (score -1):

Note this will scan the entire table:

```
SELECT TOP 1 [Col1] 
FROM [Table]
ORDER BY LEN(PARSENAME(CAST([Col1] AS VARCHAR(40)), 1)) DESC
```