# Get the number of digits after the decimal point of a float (with or without decimal part)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have following list of `Amount (float)` in my table.

```
Amount
123
123.1
123.0123
123.789456
```

How can i get the number of digits after the decimal point.

**Duplicate ?:** I have checked already existing posts, but there is no correct way to handle the **`float`** numbers **`with or without decimal part`**.

Result

```
Amount      Result
123         0
123.1       1
123.0123    4
123.789456  6
```

**EDIT** : 
After spending some valuable time, i have found some relatively simple script to handle this. My answer is [below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37024739/get-the-number-of-digits-after-the-decimal-point-of-a-float-with-or-without-dec/37027599#37027599)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I count decimal places in SQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14715141/how-do-i-count-decimal-places-in-sql)

Comment: select len(substring('123.789456',charindex('.','123.789456')+1,len('123.789456')))

Comment: @artm, Data type if float . declare @v float
set @v=0.0012
select SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(@v, 'Scale') as Scale , result is = 0 ??

Comment: @KumarHarsh : It will return 3 for the non-decimal value `select len(substring('123',charindex('.','123')+1,len('123')))`

Comment: @artm, can u plz just share the query for that fit in above list(float datatype) ? that wld be very helpful.

Comment: @Arulkumar ,great,we can use case statement then

Comment: @AbdulRasheed check my answer, hope It helps for you.

Comment: Floating point is approximate numeric. Why count decimals?

Comment: @jarlh, You are correct, but i got a request for it from another team, i don't know what is the use of this Query for them . I am looking for a relatively simple query for this.

Comment: Is anything i missed here, why this question have 2 down-votes. If you comment here please , then i can improve as much i can possible, and also that can be helpful for my future posts. (And this is not a duplicate, i didn't find any of the solution for this from the above mentioned posts by @artm).

Comment: I found some simple script (relatively to me) to handle this, answer below http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37024739/get-the-number-of-digits-after-the-decimal-point-of-a-float-with-or-without-dec/37027599#37027599

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found some simple script (relatively to me) to handle this.

```
ISNULL(NULLIF(CHARINDEX('.',REVERSE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), Amount, 128))),0) - 1,0)
```

Here the `ISNULL(NULLIF` is only to handle the float without decimal part.
If there is no values without decimal part, then it is very simple

```
CHARINDEX('.',REVERSE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), Amount, 128))) -1
```

Hope this will be helpful to you.
Full script below

```
declare @YourTable table (Amount float)
insert into @YourTable
values(123),(123.1),(123.0123),(123.789456)

SELECT  ISNULL(NULLIF(CHARINDEX('.',REVERSE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), Amount, 128))),0) - 1,0)
FROM    @YourTable

SELECT  CHARINDEX('.',REVERSE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), Amount, 128))) -1 
FROM    @YourTable
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do It in following:

**QUERY**

```
SELECT Amount, 
       CASE WHEN FLOOR(Amount) <> CEILING(Amount) THEN LEN(CONVERT(INT,CONVERT(FLOAT,REVERSE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), Amount, 128))))) ELSE 0 END AS Result
FROM YourTable
```

**OUPUT**

```
Amount      Result
123         0
123,1       1
123,0123    4
123,789456  6
```

Comment: It will fail if the float doesn't have any decimal. `DECLARE @Float FLOAT = 123; SELECT LEN(CONVERT(INT,CONVERT(FLOAT,REVERSE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), @float, 128))))) as Result;`

Comment: @Arulkumar thank you for your notice, fixed It, updated answer.

Comment: sure, so far this is good for me(but am waiting if there is any simple query without this much conversions and cast - may be :) )

Comment: For a general solution try ABS() for the Amount, because it fails on negative values :)

Answer (score 1):

Abdul Thanks for pointing my mistake.
I was not aware of peculiar behaviour of float.

```
declare @t table(Amount float)
insert into @t values (123),(123.1),(123.0123),(123.789456)
```

Here see this line will do the trick,

```
select CONVERT (VARCHAR(50), amount,128) from @t
```

Complete script,

```
select col ,case when len(col)>0 then len(col) else 0 end newcol from
(SELECT substring(REVERSE(CONVERT (VARCHAR(50), amount,128)),0,
charindex('.',REVERSE(CONVERT (VARCHAR(50), amount,128)))) col from @t)t4
```

Answer (score 0):

This code will definitely help you.

```
SELECT Amount,
       LEN(SUBSTRING(CAST(Amount as VARCHAR),CHARINDEX('.',CAST(Amount as VARCHAR))+1,LEN(Amount)))  Result
FROM [Your Table Name]
```

Answer (score 0):

And one more way:

```
SELECT  Amount,
        CASE WHEN deci = 0 THEN 0 ELSE LEN(deci) END AS Result
FROM (
    SELECT  Amount,
            TRY_CAST(REVERSE(REPLACE(Amount - TRY_CAST(Amount as int),'0.','')) as int) as deci
    FROM (VALUES
    (123),
    (123.1),
    (123.0123),
    (123.789456)
    ) as t (Amount)
) as t
```

Output:

```
Amount      Result
123.000000  0
123.100000  1
123.012300  4
123.789456  6
```

Comment: Thanks for your replay, good one, but mine one is relatively simple i think (so far), and then @Stanislovas Kalašnikovas answer.

Comment: My pleasure! I've seen your reply after posting my answer, it looks much more simple indeed.

Answer (score 0):

Since this was said to be a duplicate of this question - [SQL Server how to get money type's decimal digits?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52701469/sql-server-how-to-get-money-types-decimal-digits) - I have no choice to put my answer here.

```
/* Assumes money data type is passed in and therefore caters for overflow */
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.CountDecimalPlaces (@value decimal(30,4))  
RETURNS int
AS  
BEGIN 
    DECLARE @part decimal(30,4);
    SET @part = ABS(@value - CAST(@value as bigint));
    RETURN LEN(FORMAT(@part, '0.00##'))-2
END
```

Comment: please check the result of '1234.1', is the above function return correct result?

Comment: As I said. I was forced to put my answer here. The answer was intended for the other question which was marked as duplicate. Simply adjust this answer to suit your needs.