# SQL Server how to get money type's decimal digits?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

The column `CostPrice` of table `t1` is money type.

The data in column `CostPrice` likes this:

```
141.1938
0.00
147.1041
119.592
1.23
```

I use this sql to get the decimal digits:

```
select distinct len(CostPrice-floor(CostPrice))-2 from t1;
```

But the result is only 2,this is not right,in fact,the result should be 2,3,4.

So how to fix the sql?

**Added:**

StackOverflow does not allow me to flag the flagging but asked me to edit the question instead, so:

> This Question is not a duplicate to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37024739/6777839). The existing question is on the "float" datatype and this one is on "money", Converting "money" to "varchar" like in the "existing anser" will always return the same number of decimal places, so it does not answer this question.

Comment: what are you trying to achieve here ?

Comment: Forced to put my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/52704413/187519 - upvote it there if it helps you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could (independantly from regional settings):

- multiply the value by 10,000
- `convert` the result to integer
- `convert` the integer to a string
- add 4 leading zeroes to the left (just in case...)
- take the 4 characters from the `right` (the former decimal places)
- `replace` each zero by a blank character
- remove the trailing blanks using `rtrim`
- return the length of the remaining string

To put this in an expression, it would be:

```
LEN(RTRIM(REPLACE(RIGHT('0000' + CONVERT(varchar(20), CONVERT(int, CostPrice*10000)), 4), '0', ' ')))
```

Comment: This is helpful,thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
DECLARE 
@money money = 141.1938

 SELECT 
    @money
   ,SUBSTRING(CONVERT(varchar(20),@money,2), CHARINDEX('.', CONVERT(varchar(20),@money,2)) + 1, LEN(CONVERT(varchar(20),@money,2))) as RESULT
```