# how to find out the number of digits after a decimal point in sql server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

how to find out the number of digits after a decimal point in sql server 2008.

suppose the value is 10.12365479

I want to know how many digits are placed after the decimal point.

Note : the column is of type FLOAT.

Comment: Did you check this solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14715141/how-do-i-count-decimal-places-in-sql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use `STR` + `REPLACE` + `LEN` + `CHARINDEX` functions. Examine intermediate results below to understand how it works.

```
declare @V float = 10.12365479;

SELECT
    @V AS v
    ,STR(@V, 50, 16) AS v_str
    ,REPLACE(STR(@V, 50, 16), '0', ' ') AS v_replace
    ,LEN(REPLACE(STR(@V, 50, 16), '0', ' ')) AS v_len
    ,CHARINDEX('.', STR(@V, 50, 16)) AS v_idx

    ,LEN(REPLACE(STR(@V, 50, 16), '0', ' ')) -
    CHARINDEX('.', STR(@V, 50, 16)) AS decimal_digits
```

**Result is 8**

```
+-------------+----------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------+-------+-------+----------------+
|      v      |                       v_str                        |                     v_replace                      | v_len | v_idx | decimal_digits |
+-------------+----------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------+-------+-------+----------------+
| 10.12365479 |                                10.1236547900000000 |                                1 .12365479         |    42 |    34 |              8 |
+-------------+----------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------+-------+-------+----------------+
```

Obviously, quite often the answer will be 16 (the maximum possible), because your float value will be represented as something like `10.1236547899999999`.

Comment: its working when taking a float variable in to account..but sadly its not working with the data in the table. I replaced the variablename with my columnname..not working..thanks anyways mate.

Comment: @user1172910, "not working" is not a helpful description of the problem. If you provide more details, somebody may be able to figure out how to solve the problem.

Comment: I am sorry Vladimir Baranov..please if you apply the same query on a table with a column type float. that would give you a better picture.Thanks so much.